# How to store singe dim in array for loop through multiple work book using VBA Macro

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, file, for-loop

Scenario:

```
Workbooks.Open filename:="Core Report\DL tracker Pivot reports Wk10 FY21 - 1.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open filename:="FY21 P01 Apr 2021\PL FY2021 Adyen April-20 WK 1 - 1.xlsm"

Workbooks("PL FY2021 Adyen April-20 WK 1 - 1.xlsm").Activate
 
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink "Core Report\DL tracker Pivot reports Wk01 FY21.xlsx", _
 "Core Report\DL tracker Pivot reports Wk10 FY21 - 1.xlsx", xlExcelLinks
```

What is the code to be used by creating (Single dim in array) using loop function?

As I have done the linking for Adyen, similarly I need to do it for 15 more customer.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim wb_core as workbook
set wb_core = Workbooks.Open (filename:="Core Report\DL tracker Pivot reports Wk10 FY21 - 1.xlsx")

dim f as string
f = "FY21 P01 Apr 2021\PL FY2021 Adyen April-20 WK 1 - 1.xlsm"

' for demo purposes just use a string array but you can load this from a range on a sheet rather than hard-code
dim customers(15) as string
customers(1)= "customer 1"
...
customers(15)= "customer 15"

dim this_customer as variant
dim this_wb as workbook

for each this_customer in customers

  'replace "Adyen" with this_customer name and open workbook
  set this_wb = workbooks.open (filename:=Replace(f, "Adyen", this_customer ))
  wb.ChangeLink "Core Report\DL tracker Pivot reports Wk01 FY21.xlsx", _
      "Core Report\DL tracker Pivot reports Wk10 FY21 - 1.xlsx", xlExcelLinks

  'if you want to save then save/close here with wb.save/wb.close

next this_customer
```

Comment: This exactly fits my requirement and i am bit new to VBA.                                                                                              Could you please help me to understand what is   for this_customer in customers in the above. Do i need to replace anything over there.

Comment: Hi @KrishnaBehera - I'm glad it was helpful. Actually there was a little typo in what i sent it should be `for each ...`: from the microsoft docs, `For Each ... next Repeats a group of statements for each element in an array or collection` - basically its is an iteration through each member of a collection/array.

Comment: The array here is the `customers` array and `for each this_customer in customers ... next this_customer` so the code loops through every item in the array, puts that item into the variable `this_customer` and executes the code. its equivalent to the for loop `for i = 0 to 14/this_customer=customers(i) ...` take a look at the ms docs (link below) and if the answer is acceptable could you upvote/mark as the solution the sanswer I submitted? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement